# Set the affinity of a process from a shell script as it is being launched

Tags: linux, shell-script, process-management

I have a script (.sh) where I launch applications like this

```
#!/bin/sh
./application1 configuration1.cfg  param1 param2 param3 &

sleep 2

./application2 configuration2.cfg  param1 param2 param3 &

sleep 2
```

etc

**Is there a way that I can assign the CPU affinity as I launch the process?**

I don't really want to do it after the fact. I could do it programatically from C++, but it seems that the shell is the best way to do it.

**Then, once launched, how do I verify that it is indeed stuck to that CPU/core?**

Answer (score 4):

There is a utility, [`taskset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset),
part of util-linux, for just this purpose. For example:

```
taskset -c 0-15 script
```

will run `script` and constrain it to use just CPUs with IDs 0 to 15.

To check that your scripts are indeed constrained to run on the proper
CPUs, you can look at the file `/proc/<pid>/status`: it will have
entries named `Cpus_allowed` (a bitmap; the least significant bit is
set if CPU 0 is allowed) and `Cpus_allowed_list` (a
list of CPU IDs).

Comment: Hmmm, strange, when I add taskset to run the script from the command line, or I add taskset in front of each program that I am starting inside the script, my program behaves completely differently and wrong.

Comment: If you can describe the issue in more detail, that could be material for a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm mid "learning experience" myself, but this might be relevant.

To run a bash script in the background on a specific cpu, try:

`taskset -c 1 ./myScript &`

In myScript include the lines:

`echo MyScript: $$\($BASHPID\)
taskset -cp $BASHPID`

$BASHPID, which is new to me, is: "The process ID of the current Bash process. In some cases, this can differ from $$."

Personally I'm struggling to run a bash function in the background on a specific cpu.

`taskset -c 1 ./myFunction &`

... gave me: taskset: failed to execute myFunction: No such file or directory

While after some false starts

`(taskset -cp 1 $BASHPID;myFunction)&`

... looks promising.